# Building Report Logic on Two Datasets

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am building a report which must meet the following conditions on two datasets, extracted from two different data sources:

> **DATASET 1: From a SharePoint List DataSource**
>
> If Status = “Eligible to Move” **OR** “Pending QA/QC Review” **OR**
>   “Re-Exam Completed”
>
> ***AND IF:***
>
> **DATASET 2: From a SQL Server Database DataSource**
>
> Schedule 1st Briefing Date is blank **OR** (1st Briefing Attendance =
>   No Show **AND** Schedule 2nd Briefing Date is blank) **OR** (2nd
>   Briefing Attendance = No Show) **OR** (Schedule 1st Briefing Date is a
>   date prior to today’s date AND 1st Briefing Attendance is blank)
>   **OR** (Schedule 2nd Briefing Date is a date prior to today’s date **AND** 2nd Briefing Attendance is blank)

I did this by adding filters to both data sources using expressions that model the logic above, and then doing a lookup in a table which uses DataSet1 Customer ID to match DataSet2 Customer ID and returns an issue status (peculiar to DataSet2). **I could not add DataSet 2 fields to the DataSet 1 table, which is why I did the lookup.** However this is not working. I have added my code for DataSet2 filtration below, in case something might be wrong with it.

***I should also add I had the datasources and datasets set up for me in the report as I don't have credentials, but I was able to add filters to the datasets.***

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!FirstBriefingDate.Value) 
or (Fields!FirstBriefingAttendance.Value = "No Show" and 
IsNothing(Fields!SecondBriefingDate.Value)) or 
Fields!SecondBriefingAttendance.Value = "No Show" or 
(Fields!FirstBriefingDate.Value<Today() and 
IsNothing(Fields!FirstBriefingAttendance.Value)) or 
(Fields!SecondBriefingDate.Value<Today() and 
IsNothing(Fields!SecondBriefingAttendance.Value)), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I just had to apply the filters for the second dataset in the SQL query itself. I ended up needing the credentials for these.